# How does Reactive's Monad instance handle simultaneous events?

Tags: haskell, frp

In [*Push-Pull Functional Reactive Programming*](http://conal.net/papers/push-pull-frp/push-pull-frp.pdf) by Conal Elliot, `Reactive`s are given a `Monad` instance in section 7.1.3. What happens if both the inner and outer reactive fire that the same time for `join`?

```hs
never :: Event a
MkFuture :: Time -> a -> Future a
pure :: a -> Future a -- at time zero
MkReactive :: a -> Event a -> Reactive a
MkEvent :: Future (Reactive a) -> Event a

join (MkReactive (MkReactive "foo" never) (MkEvent (pure (MkReactive "bar" never)))
```

Should `"foo"` be ignored or included in the result on the join?

Comment: The question doesn't make sense -- `join` essentially waits for the first `Event a` to arrive. Since `never` (presumably) never  does arrive, `join` waits forever and the result is `_|_` (bottom).

Comment: @BobDalgleish `(MkEvent (pure (MkReactive "bar" never)))` fires at time zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the (slightly paraphrased) `join` definition from section 7.1.3:

```
-- urr is the outer Reactive; ur is the inner one.
joinR :: Reactive (Reactive a) -> Reactive a
joinR ((a `Stepper` Ev ur) `Stepper` Ev urr) = a `Stepper` Ev u
    where
    u = ((`switcher` Ev urr) <$> ur) <> (join <$> urr)
```

The `Monoid` instance being used in the definition of `u` is the one for `Future`s, defined in section 4.5, which in case of simultaneous firings picks the left one. That being so, the inner firing is not discarded if there is a simultaneous firing in `join`. For the specific example in your question, sampling at time zero should still give out `"foo"`. (I believe the monad law `join . fmap return = id` would be violated if that wasn't the case)